# Where do the distance metrics for the Krippendorff's alpha statistic come from?

Tags: distance, reliability, metric, agreement-statistics

The intercoder reliability statistic Krippendorff's alpha is nice because it can be used across many different types of data: nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio, circular, etc.  To do so, you just substitute a different distance metric into the reliability calculation.  See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff%27s_Alpha) for a good description.

My question: where do these distance metrics come from?  Are they uniquely determined for a given data type?  Are there certain desiderata they satisfy?  I've read Krippendorff's content analysis book, and everything else I could find on the topic, and no luck...

Comment: Doesn't [the section on difference functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff%27s_Alpha#Difference_functions) in the Wikipedia article directly answer this question?

Comment: Only partly.  The section describes some of the basic metric properties (but no mention of the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Metric_space)), but doesn't answer the question of whether the distance functions *uniquely* satisfy these requirements.  If not, why are these metrics used instead of others?  Also, is the triangle inequality one of the criteria used for Krippendorff's metrics?